# confused about the limit of a trigonometric function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the limit of the following function for general $a$:

$$\lim_{x\to a}[\cos(2 \pi x)-\sin(2 \pi x) \cot(\frac{\pi x}{a})]$$

I was believing this is infinite. But *Mathematica* calculates for $a=3$ for instance the limit is $5$

And for $a$ in general *Mathematica* returns an infinit term that says:

DirectedInfinity[a Sin[2 a [Pi]]]

I can not understand the role of $a\sin(2a \pi)$

May someone here ehlp me out of confusion?

Comment: $\cot\pi$ is infinite, so for most values of $a$ the limit will not exist. But if $a$ is chosen so $\sin2\pi a=0$, maybe the limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirectedInfinity` is, I believe, a term that Mathematica uses to indicate a limit of infinity in the complex plane. If $a_n$ is an increasing sequence of positive numbers and $k$ is some complex number, then the limit of $ka_n$ will be expressed as `DirectedInfinity[k]`. (And the same for sequences that approach this type of sequence.) In the case where $a$ is real, it just means that the expression tends to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, and the sign of $a \sin(2a\pi)$ will tell you which one.

As for the first part of your question, I think that Mathematica is substituing $x=3$ and rearranging your expression to get something like
$$ \cos(\pi) [ \frac{\cos(6\pi)}{\cos(\pi)} - \frac{\sin(6\pi)}{\sin(\pi)} ]$$.

Since $\cos(6\pi)$ can be expressed as a sixth-degree polynomial in $\cos(\pi)$ and the same for $\sin$, the part in brackets probably ends up evaluating to $-5 + 0$ or similar.

This might not be what you want, but it could be what someone else wants when writing this expression. Try the limit for $a$ not an integer, and this simplification shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$F=\cos 2\pi x-\sin 2\pi x\cot \frac{\pi x}a$$

$$=\frac{\sin \frac{\pi x}a\cos 2\pi x-\sin 2\pi x\cos \frac{\pi x}a}{\sin \frac{\pi x}a}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi x}a-2\pi x)}{\sin \frac{\pi x}a}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi x}a(1-2a))}{\sin \frac{\pi x}a}$$

If $1-2a$ is integer, $\lim_{x\to a}F=\frac00,$ we can apply L' Hospital Rule

Else the  denominator goes to zero, but the numerator doesn't, hence, the limit goes to $\infty$

Comment: The denominator goes to zero, but the numerator doesn't (except for certain values of $a$), so l'Hopital doesn't apply (except for those values of $a$).

Comment: @GerryMyerson,  how about the current version?

Comment: Much better.${}$

Comment: when applying l'Hospital's rule I really get $\cos(2\pi a)$ as the limit for $a$ integer. Is this magic really true?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi, that's how the problem is designed:)